# MySql.Data.MySqlClient Reference Not Working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I've been attempting to connect a MySql database to my project in Visual Studio 2015. In order to connect it in the Server Explorer, I had to download and add the reference to my project. Easy peasy.

Then, when I attempted to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822392/Connecting-to-MySQL-from-ASP-NET-MVC-using-Visual), I get this error message:

[image]

*The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I have indeed added the assembly reference (I believe, if I understand the term correctly), by checking the MySql.Data in the References/Extension.

[image]

Am I using the wrong MySql.Data? How do I know which one? I've read that perhaps it can have to do with mixed versions of .NET Frameworks, but honestly I don't know how to check.

I'm an up-and-coming programmer, who before this, had only worked with static, hard-coded webpages, and never used databases in a project before.

EDIT: I have indeed added the 'using MySql.Data.MySqlClient to the same class file as I am attempting to use it in.

[image]

[image]
More information. What is displayed when I hover over the Data in MySql.Data.MySqlClient in the 'using' statements.

Comment: The error message, and the quickaction window, are telling you that it needs you to specify the full name to the type or else add MySql.Data.MySqlClient to the using statements.

Comment: What errors are you getting on that using statement?  Intellisense is unhappy.

Comment: Edited my post to show more information on that.

Comment: It appears that you have this namespace (MySql.Data) repeated, somewhere, in your project.  Can you verify that?

Comment: It has been verified. I attempted to search for MySql.Data before, and found nothing. It just now dawned on me how to actually look for it. Thank you for finding such a simple issue. If you submit an answer, I'll select it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first screenshot shows the quickactions window suggesting that you use a fully qualified name, for the type, because it cannot determine where the type comes from.

Search to make sure that MySql.Data is not used, as a namespace, elsewhere in your project, so that it does not collide with the MySql.Data namespace from the dll you are referencing.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick replies. I certainly won't be overlooking something like that again!